# encrypt video file using action script 3 and play it from maim swf

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to make **flash swf** for play **encrypted flv/MP4** videos. I tried this.. [HTTP://www.veryinteractivepeople.com/?p=525](http://www.veryinteractivepeople.com/?p=525)

Here we want to put flv file in to the swf and encrypt it. But I want to encrypt flv/MP4 separately and play from main swf

I am not a **expert about Action script 3**. But I try. Please tell me some solution for this.

Comment: What have you really tried yourself? And what way are you going to achieve your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a null net connection and net stream to prepare a video in "data generation mode".  Then load encrypted bytes with a URLRequest, decrypt them, and append the bytes to a net stream.

```
var nc = new NetConnection(null);
var ns = new NetStream(nc);

var encryptedBytes = .. get encrypted bytes from URLRequest ...

var decryptedBytes = .. your decryption function ..

ns.appendBytes(decryptedBytes);
var video = new Video();
addChild(video);
video.attachNetStream(ns);
ns.play(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code....
http://www.veryinteractivepeople.com/?p=525

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    [SWF(width="770", height="490", frameRate="31", backgroundColor="#FFFFFF")]
    public class ProtectedSWF extends Sprite
    {
        //replace "encrypted.swf" to the name of your encrypted SWF file 
        [Embed(source="encrypted.swf", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
        private const EmbeddedSWF:Class;

        //put your encryption key here
        private static const KEY:String="WRITE_YOUR_OWN_CODE!";

        public function ProtectedSWF()
        {
            var binaryData:ByteArray = new EmbeddedSWF();
            if(binaryData.length != 0)
            {
                XOR(binaryData,KEY);
                var animationLoader:Loader = new Loader();
                animationLoader.loadBytes(binaryData);
                addChild(animationLoader);
            }
        }
        private static function  XOR(binaryData:ByteArray, key:String):void{
            var keyIndex:Number=0;
            for(var i:Number=0;i<binaryData.length;i++){
                binaryData[i]=binaryData[i]^key.charCodeAt(keyIndex);
                keyIndex++;
                if(keyIndex>=key.length)
                    keyIndex=0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```